# What is this plant with serrated narrow leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I left my fern outside like I do every year. When its leaves fell off this year, an odd plant was growing in with it.

Does any one know what this plant is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't recognise it - if you're not sure whether its something you want to keep, extract it from the pot, carefully, keeping the roots intact, and repot into a separate container, see how it grows.

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be a verbena? The leaves would smell citrus like when bruised.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever by a chance dropped a peach pit or are you from a subtropical or temperate part of the world? Looks like a peach seedling to me.